# MobX How to Initialize Store with nested models

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mobx, mobx-react

## Trouble setting/initializing store with nested models. Example below.

The problem is when I try to set the store on the parent ForumStoreModel.forums -> I will get an error because the ForumModels field `posts` can only be set from `actions`. But they can't be set yet because the forum hasn't been yet created... ?

```js
const PostModel = types
  .model("Post")
  .props({
    id: types.string,
    content: types.string,
  })

const ForumModel = types
  .model("Forum")
  .props({
    id: types.string,
    city: types.string,
    posts: types.map(PostModel),
  })
  .actions((self) => ({
    addPost(postId: string, postData: typeof PostModel) {
      self.posts.set(postId, postData))
    }
  }))

const ForumStoreModel = types
  .model("ForumStore")
  .props({
    forums: types.map(ForumModel),
  })
  .actions((self) => ({
      addForum(forumId: string, forumData: typeof ForumModel) {
        // Error Here - forumData type
        self.forums.set(forumId, forumData )
      }
  })
  .actions((store) => ({
    async fetchForum(formId: string) {
      try {
        const retForm = await fetchExternalData();
        if (retForm.success) {
          const adaptForumToMobX = {
            id: retForm.id,
            city: retForm.city,
            posts: [],
          }
          store.addForum(forumData.id, adaptForumToMobX)
        }
      } catch (e) {
        return console.log("Error fetching specific forum", e)
      }
    },
  ))


ForumStoreModel.fetchForum("<some-id>")
```